# Variable target file with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'd like to start by saying that I would rather any suggestions didn't include JQuery; I don't like how JQuery has become a defacto standard within JavaScript.
So here's my problem:
I'd like to pass a variable to a function that then uses that variable as the path to the file in a .open(). Here's my code so far:
Example of function being called:
`ajaxPost('chatlog.txt',null);`

The function being called:

```
function ajaxPost(targetPath,toSend){
    var getMessage;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        getMessage=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        getMessage=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        alert("Stop using Internet Explorer.");
    }
    getMessage.open("POST",targetPath,true);
    getMessage.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (getMessage.readyState==4 && getMessage.status==200){
            alert(getMessage.responseText);
        }
    };
    getMessage.send(toSend);
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work, for some kabuki reason.

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/cKE8p/

Comment: Strange... I'm using it at [link](http://thepeckingbird.com/chat/testchat.php), the only difference seems to be that where I'm using it the function is in an external js file.

Comment: Your server is returning 405 "Not allowed", so the issue isn't the ajax function, it's something else, probably on the serverside.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'll investigate into that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some logical issue in your code:

- the whole idea of using `POST` method is to send any kind of data to a specific backend and do server side stuff based on that data, but here you are using `POST` method to actually `GET` the `'chatlog.txt'`. so you had to use `GET` method, to begin with.
- BUT if you still insist on using `POST` instead of `GET`, you should know that you can use POST method instead of GET and it does the same, but you would face with some unforeseen problems.

**YOUR ACTUAL PROBLEM:**

I loaded your actual page and saw your problem, you have a error in your console:

> **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

and as I said it means you have to change your method. I changed it like this:

```
function ajaxPost(targetPath,toSend){
    var getMessage;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    getMessage=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        getMessage=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        alert("Stop using Internet Explorer.");
    }
    getMessage.open("GET",targetPath,true);
    getMessage.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (getMessage.readyState==4 && getMessage.status==200){
            alert(getMessage.responseText);
        }
    };
    getMessage.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    getMessage.send(toSend);
}
```

and it returned a data like this:

```
<b>Peck:</b> Hello World!<br/>#
<b>World:</b> Hello Peck!<br/>#
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
getMessage.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Before you send it. It tells the server how to process the POST stuff.

Comment: I should as that to the question's code, as that didn't resolve the problem. Thank you anyway though!

Answer (score -1):

Using XMLHttpRequest is a very bad idea. If you are already using JQuery, try something like this:

```
$.post( "test.php", {name: "John", time: "2pm"}).done(function( data )
{
  alert ("Succes! Data received: " + data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, however I'm looking to _not_ use Jquery.